# Making a mega menu responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a menu I've adapted responsive, to use a burger menu on mobile devices.

Here is the original HTML, CSS (it uses Tailwind) and JavaScript:

```js
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const menuToggle = document.getElementById('menu-toggle');
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

    menuToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
      menu.classList.toggle('show');
    });
  });
  </body>
```

```css
.mega-menu {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

/* #hoverable Class Styles */
.hoverable {
    position: static;
}

.hoverable > a:after {
    content: "\25BC";
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}

.hoverable:hover .mega-menu {
    display: block;
}

/* #toggle Class Styles */
.toggleable > label:after {
    content: "\25BC";
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}

.toggle-input {
    display: none;
}

.toggle-input:not(checked) ~ .mega-menu {
    display: none;
}

.toggle-input:checked ~ .mega-menu {
    display: block;
}

.toggle-input:checked + label {
    color: white;
    background: rgb(3, 102, 114);

    /* @apply bg-teal-700 */
}

.toggle-input:checked ~ label:after {
    content: "\25B2";
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}

/* Responsive styles */
@media (max-width: 1023px) {
    .menu {
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: white;
    }

    .menu.show {
        display: flex;
    }

    .menu > ul > li {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu > ul > li > a {
        display: block;
    }

    .mega-menu {
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.mobile-menu {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1023px) {
    .mobile-menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        padding: 1rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.1.2/tailwind.min.css'>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar relative bg-white border-b-2 border-gray-300 text-gray-900" style="z-index: 100;">
            <div class="container mx-auto flex justify-between">
                <div class="relative block p-4 lg:p-6 text-xl text-teal-600 font-bold">
                    <a href="#" class="hover:text-teal-900">Logo</a>
                </div>
                <button class="lg:hidden text-teal-600 hover:text-teal-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-teal-900" id="menu-toggle" aria-label="Menu Toggle">
                    <svg class="h-6 w-6 fill-current" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path d="M4 5h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <div class="menu hidden lg:flex">
                    <ul class="flex">
                        <!--Regular Link-->
                        <li class="hover:bg-teal-700 hover:text-white">
                            <a href="#" class="relative block py-6 px-2 lg:p-6 text-sm lg:text-base font-bold">navlink</a>
                        </li>
                        <!--Hoverable Link-->
                        <li class="hoverable hover:bg-teal-700 hover:text-white">
                            <a href="#" class="relative block py-6 px-4 lg:p-6 text-sm lg:text-base font-bold hover:bg-teal-700 hover:text-white">Hover to show</a>
                            <div class="p-6 mega-menu mb-16 sm:mb-0 shadow-xl bg-teal-700">
                                <div class="container mx-auto w-full flex flex-wrap justify-between mx-2">
                                    <div class="w-full text-white mb-8 text-center">
                                        <h2 class="font-bold text-2xl">Listen, why don’t you wait out by the speeder.</h2>
                                        <p>our droids. They’ll have to wait outside. We don’t want them here.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="px-4 w-full sm:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 border-gray-600 border-b sm:border-r lg:border-b-0 pb-6 pt-6 lg:pt-3">
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                            <svg class="h-8 mb-3 mr-3 fill-current text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M3 6c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h8l4-4h2v16h-2l-4-4H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2H1V6h2zm8 9v5H8l-1.67-5H5v-2h8v2h-2z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <h3 class="font-bold text-xl text-white text-bold mb-2">Tatooine</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="text-gray-100 text-sm">Thul klivian doldur thisspiasian calrissian. Garindan d8 aurra twi'lek tund polis gen'dai sola tarpals.</p>
                                        <div class="flex items-center py-3">
                                            <svg class="h-6 pr-3 fill-current text-teal-300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M20 10a10 10 0 1 1-20 0 10 10 0 0 1 20 0zm-2 0a8 8 0 1 0-16 0 8 8 0 0 0 16 0zm-8 2H5V8h5V5l5 5-5 5v-3z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <a href="#" class="text-white bold border-b-2 border-teal-300 hover:text-teal-900">Find out more...</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="px-4 w-full sm:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 border-gray-600 border-b sm:border-r-0 lg:border-r lg:border-b-0 pb-6 pt-6 lg:pt-3">
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                            <svg class="h-8 mb-3 mr-3 fill-current text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M4.13 12H4a2 2 0 1 0 1.8 1.11L7.86 10a2.03 2.03 0 0 0 .65-.07l1.55 1.55a2 2 0 1 0 3.72-.37L15.87 8H16a2 2 0 1 0-1.8-1.11L12.14 10a2.03 2.03 0 0 0-.65.07L9.93 8.52a2 2 0 1 0-3.72.37L4.13 12zM0 4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h16a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <h3 class="font-bold text-xl text-white text-bold mb-2">Cantonica</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="text-gray-100 text-sm">Thul klivian doldur thisspiasian calrissian. Garindan d8 aurra twi'lek tund polis gen'dai sola tarpals.</p>
                                        <div class="flex items-center py-3">
                                            <svg class="h-6 pr-3 fill-current text-teal-300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M20 10a10 10 0 1 1-20 0 10 10 0 0 1 20 0zm-2 0a8 8 0 1 0-16 0 8 8 0 0 0 16 0zm-8 2H5V8h5V5l5 5-5 5v-3z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <a href="#" class="text-white bold border-b-2 border-teal-300 hover:text-teal-900">Find out more...</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="px-4 w-full sm:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 border-gray-600 border-b sm:border-b-0 sm:border-r md:border-b-0 pb-6 pt-6 lg:pt-3">
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                            <svg class="h-8 mb-3 mr-3 fill-current text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M2 4v14h14v-6l2-2v10H0V2h10L8 4H2zm10.3-.3l4 4L8 16H4v-4l8.3-8.3zm1.4-1.4L16 0l4 4-2.3 2.3-4-4z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <h3 class="font-bold text-xl text-white text-bold mb-2">Yavin 4</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="text-gray-100 text-sm">Thul klivian doldur thisspiasian calrissian. Garindan d8 aurra twi'lek tund polis gen'dai sola tarpals.</p>
                                        <div class="flex items-center py-3">
                                            <svg class="h-6 pr-3 fill-current text-teal-300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M20 10a10 10 0 1 1-20 0 10 10 0 0 1 20 0zm-2 0a8 8 0 1 0-16 0 8 8 0 0 0 16 0zm-8 2H5V8h5V5l5 5-5 5v-3z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <a href="#" class="text-white bold border-b-2 border-teal-300 hover:text-teal-900">Find out more...</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="px-4 w-full sm:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 border-gray-600 pb-6 pt-6 lg:pt-3">
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                            <svg class="h-8 mb-3 mr-3 fill-current text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M9 12H1v6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h14a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-6h-8v2H9v-2zm0-1H0V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v1h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v6h-9V9H9v2zm3-8V2H8v1h4z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <h3 class="font-bold text-xl text-white text-bold mb-2">Alderaan</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="text-gray-100 text-sm">Thul klivian doldur thisspiasian calrissian. Garindan d8 aurra twi'lek tund polis gen'dai sola tarpals.</p>
                                        <div class="flex items-center py-3">
                                            <svg class="h-6 pr-3 fill-current text-teal-300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M20 10a10 10 0 1 1-20 0 10 10 0 0 1 20 0zm-2 0a8 8 0 1 0-16 0 8 8 0 0 0 16 0zm-8 2H5V8h5V5l5 5-5 5v-3z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <a href="#" class="text-white bold border-b-2 border-teal-300 hover:text-teal-900">Find out more...</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!--end Hoverable Link-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

The bit I'm struggling with is how to make the mobile version tidier. Ideally, I'd want the menu items stacked vertically instead of next to each other and for the entire menu to fly out rather than drop down.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: @media (max-width: 1023px) {
ul.flex {
    flex-direction: column;
}
}

try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with the display flex in the `<ul>` holder of links. In Tailwind you can use `md:` (for exemple) to make responsive styles.

```html
<head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.1.2/tailwind.min.css'>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar relative bg-white border-b-2 border-gray-300 text-gray-900" style="z-index: 100;">
            <div class="container mx-auto flex justify-between">
                <div class="relative block p-4 lg:p-6 text-xl text-teal-600 font-bold">
                    <a href="#" class="hover:text-teal-900">Logo</a>
                </div>
                <button class="lg:hidden text-teal-600 hover:text-teal-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-teal-900" id="menu-toggle" aria-label="Menu Toggle">
                    <svg class="h-6 w-6 fill-current" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path d="M4 5h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <div class="menu hidden lg:flex">
                    <ul class="md:flex">
                        <!--Regular Link-->
                        <li class="hover:bg-teal-700 hover:text-white">
                            <a href="#" class="relative block py-6 px-2 lg:p-6 text-sm lg:text-base font-bold">navlink</a>
                        </li>
                        <!--Hoverable Link-->
                        <li class="hoverable hover:bg-teal-700 hover:text-white">
                            <a href="#" class="relative block py-6 px-4 lg:p-6 text-sm lg:text-base font-bold hover:bg-teal-700 hover:text-white">Hover to show</a>
                            <div class="p-6 mega-menu mb-16 sm:mb-0 shadow-xl bg-teal-700">
                                <div class="container mx-auto w-full flex flex-wrap justify-between mx-2">
                                    <div class="w-full text-white mb-8 text-center">
                                        <h2 class="font-bold text-2xl">Listen, why don’t you wait out by the speeder.</h2>
                                        <p>our droids. They’ll have to wait outside. We don’t want them here.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="px-4 w-full sm:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 border-gray-600 border-b sm:border-r lg:border-b-0 pb-6 pt-6 lg:pt-3">
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                            <svg class="h-8 mb-3 mr-3 fill-current text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M3 6c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h8l4-4h2v16h-2l-4-4H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2H1V6h2zm8 9v5H8l-1.67-5H5v-2h8v2h-2z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <h3 class="font-bold text-xl text-white text-bold mb-2">Tatooine</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="text-gray-100 text-sm">Thul klivian doldur thisspiasian calrissian. Garindan d8 aurra twi'lek tund polis gen'dai sola tarpals.</p>
                                        <div class="flex items-center py-3">
                                            <svg class="h-6 pr-3 fill-current text-teal-300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M20 10a10 10 0 1 1-20 0 10 10 0 0 1 20 0zm-2 0a8 8 0 1 0-16 0 8 8 0 0 0 16 0zm-8 2H5V8h5V5l5 5-5 5v-3z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <a href="#" class="text-white bold border-b-2 border-teal-300 hover:text-teal-900">Find out more...</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="px-4 w-full sm:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 border-gray-600 border-b sm:border-r-0 lg:border-r lg:border-b-0 pb-6 pt-6 lg:pt-3">
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                            <svg class="h-8 mb-3 mr-3 fill-current text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M4.13 12H4a2 2 0 1 0 1.8 1.11L7.86 10a2.03 2.03 0 0 0 .65-.07l1.55 1.55a2 2 0 1 0 3.72-.37L15.87 8H16a2 2 0 1 0-1.8-1.11L12.14 10a2.03 2.03 0 0 0-.65.07L9.93 8.52a2 2 0 1 0-3.72.37L4.13 12zM0 4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h16a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <h3 class="font-bold text-xl text-white text-bold mb-2">Cantonica</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="text-gray-100 text-sm">Thul klivian doldur thisspiasian calrissian. Garindan d8 aurra twi'lek tund polis gen'dai sola tarpals.</p>
                                        <div class="flex items-center py-3">
                                            <svg class="h-6 pr-3 fill-current text-teal-300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M20 10a10 10 0 1 1-20 0 10 10 0 0 1 20 0zm-2 0a8 8 0 1 0-16 0 8 8 0 0 0 16 0zm-8 2H5V8h5V5l5 5-5 5v-3z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <a href="#" class="text-white bold border-b-2 border-teal-300 hover:text-teal-900">Find out more...</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="px-4 w-full sm:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 border-gray-600 border-b sm:border-b-0 sm:border-r md:border-b-0 pb-6 pt-6 lg:pt-3">
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                            <svg class="h-8 mb-3 mr-3 fill-current text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M2 4v14h14v-6l2-2v10H0V2h10L8 4H2zm10.3-.3l4 4L8 16H4v-4l8.3-8.3zm1.4-1.4L16 0l4 4-2.3 2.3-4-4z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <h3 class="font-bold text-xl text-white text-bold mb-2">Yavin 4</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="text-gray-100 text-sm">Thul klivian doldur thisspiasian calrissian. Garindan d8 aurra twi'lek tund polis gen'dai sola tarpals.</p>
                                        <div class="flex items-center py-3">
                                            <svg class="h-6 pr-3 fill-current text-teal-300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M20 10a10 10 0 1 1-20 0 10 10 0 0 1 20 0zm-2 0a8 8 0 1 0-16 0 8 8 0 0 0 16 0zm-8 2H5V8h5V5l5 5-5 5v-3z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <a href="#" class="text-white bold border-b-2 border-teal-300 hover:text-teal-900">Find out more...</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="px-4 w-full sm:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 border-gray-600 pb-6 pt-6 lg:pt-3">
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                            <svg class="h-8 mb-3 mr-3 fill-current text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M9 12H1v6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h14a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-6h-8v2H9v-2zm0-1H0V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v1h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v6h-9V9H9v2zm3-8V2H8v1h4z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <h3 class="font-bold text-xl text-white text-bold mb-2">Alderaan</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="text-gray-100 text-sm">Thul klivian doldur thisspiasian calrissian. Garindan d8 aurra twi'lek tund polis gen'dai sola tarpals.</p>
                                        <div class="flex items-center py-3">
                                            <svg class="h-6 pr-3 fill-current text-teal-300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                <path d="M20 10a10 10 0 1 1-20 0 10 10 0 0 1 20 0zm-2 0a8 8 0 1 0-16 0 8 8 0 0 0 16 0zm-8 2H5V8h5V5l5 5-5 5v-3z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <a href="#" class="text-white bold border-b-2 border-teal-300 hover:text-teal-900">Find out more...</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!--end Hoverable Link-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

See more here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

Comment: did you get it?

Comment: Yup, that's perfect, solves the stacking issue nicely. Thank you.

Comment: can you mark the answer as right, to help others, pelase?